# ionic 3 showing error src/android/com/tkyaji/cordova/DecryptResource.java not found

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi thank you for this cordova-plugin-crypt-file plugin a few day ago I used this plugin into my many projects and it's working good but today I create new project with ionic 2 and add android platform after that I try to used your plugin and on create build time it's first showing encrypt process and encrypt all html css and javascript file but after that it's showing me error on terminal with  src/android/com/tkyaji/cordova/DecryptResource.java not found  not found and my build process is stops and also hooks are not created on ionic 3 latest project

Comment: Both answer is good for me but now i am confused which one i accept as a answer..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Awaiting the update, you can apply this manual fix. 
Open plugins/cordova-plugin-crypt-file/hooks/after_prepare.js and change line 58 from

```
var pluginDir = path.join(platformPath, 'src');
```

to

```
var pluginDir = path.join(platformPath, 'app/src/main/java');
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed a few days ago (see https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file/pull/63).

There was nothing released after this merged pull request but you can use the git repository directly fixing your issue.

`cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-cryptfile`

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file.git#03a57e79f068f9ef063c8262b60e778e55eece18`